# RPC Timeout in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timeout, cql

I get the following error:

```
cqlsh:dev> SELECT DISTINCT id FROM raw_data;
Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.
```

This is a special query that I'll never make again, I don't care how long it takes, and I don't want to change my schema (since I'll never make the query again...).

**How can I increase `rpc_timeout` for this one query?**

I have tried adding `LIMIT 9999` and `ALLOW FILTERING`, and it doesn't help. I expect less than 1000 rows in the result. The query works on another Cassandra cluster with half as much data.

Edit: as it turns out, this particular command succeeded after I ran `nodetool compact`, but what I'm more interested in the general case of temporarily increasing `rpc_timeout` for one query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

increase the read request time in cassandra.yaml file under /cassandra/conf

```
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
```

change this restart server and execute your query, might be your problem get resolved.