# Reading error in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm having a weir error trying to read data from a Cassandra table. I have a single-node installation, with the default setup. This is the query I'm making:

```
  SELECT component_id,
         reading_1,
         reading_2,
         reading_3,
         date
  FROM component_readings
  WHERE park_id=2
        AND component_id IN (479)
        AND date >= '2016-04-09+0000'
        AND date <= '2016-05-08+0000';
```

`component_readings` is a simple table, with no clustering conditions:

```
CREATE TABLE component_readings (
    park_id int,
    component_id int,
    date timestamp,
    reading_1 decimal,
    reading_2 decimal,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((park_id), component_id, date)
);
```

With some `component_id` values, it works, and with another values, it fails. This is the error I'm getting:

```
cassandra.ReadFailure: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] 
message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures"
info={'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1,
'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}
```

And the cassandra's system.log shows this error:

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2016-05-09 15:33:58,872 StorageProxy.java:1818 - 
Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM xrem.component_readings
WHERE park_id, component_id = 2, 479 AND date >= 2016-04-09 02:00+0200 AND date <=
2016-05-08 02:00+0200 LIMIT 5000' (last scanned row partion key was ((2, 479),
2016-05-04 17:30+0200)); query aborted
```

The weird thing is that I get the error only when making the query from an external program (via the python cassandra-connector). If I make it directly in the cqlsh shell, it works perfectly.

My installation was cassandra 2.2, but I've upgraded to 3.5, and I get the same error.

Comment: what happens if you set the consistency level to quorum in a request?

Comment: Same problem: `cassandra.ReadFailure: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'QUORUM'}`

Comment: you only have one replica?

Comment: Yes. As I said, it's a single-node installation.

Comment: then quorum thing was stupid sorry

Comment: can you show us the log?

Comment: The log shows this error, I'll update the question: `ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2016-05-09 15:33:58,872 StorageProxy.java:1818 - Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM xrem.component_readings WHERE park_id, component_id = 2, 479 AND date >= 2016-04-09 02:00+0200 AND date <= 2016-05-08 02:00+0200 LIMIT 5000' (last scanned row partion key was ((2, 479), 2016-05-04 17:30+0200)); query aborted`

Comment: if this is really a tombstones problem, have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340812/cassandra-timing-out-when-queried-for-key-that-have-over-10-000-rows-even-after?

Comment: I did, but I don't update the table a lot. I make inserts daily from a crontab, and then it's just readings. I don't understand where the tombstones problem come from.

Comment: You have a ... in your table definition, but is there a collection of some sort in there?

Comment: No, the `...` are just some more decimal columns.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are exceeding the `tombstone_failure_threshold`. It defaults to 100'000. You can either

- increase the value in the cassandra.yaml or
- clean up your tombstones

To do the latter [alter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html) your table and set the gc_grace_seconds to 0:

```
ALTER TABLE component_readings WITH GC_GRACE_SECONDS = 0;
```

Then trigger a compaction via the nodetool. This will flush out all tombstones.

In your particular scenario of a one-node-cluster you could leave the GC_GRACE_SECONDS at zero. But if you do, keep in mind to undo this if you ever want to use more than one node!

Comment: But if the problem are the tombstones, why does the query work if I launch it from cqlsh and fails from the external program? It doesn't make sense to me (BTW, the solution works, but I don't understand why).

Comment: @CésarGarcíaTapia, yes, I agree that it is strange. Currently there are several tickets open about some inconsistent tombstone counting/behavior or other that affect the 3.x branches. Maybe you are affected by one such? You could raise a bug ticket.

Comment: I observe similar inconsistency: query fails with `paging off`, but finishes correctly with `paging on`. `show version`: cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.5 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4.

Comment: In case you are dealing with Materialized views you wont be able to set it to 0; but you can set it still to a low value say 10 seconds.........
you will get a message like`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot alter gc_grace_seconds of the base table of a materialized view to 0, since this value is used to TTL undelivered updates. Setting gc_grace_seconds too low might cause undelivered updates to expire before being replayed."