# Cassandra select query fails while executing filter in between timestamp

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql

I am trying to execute the query :

```
select key,date,time_stamp,value from archive_all where time_stamp > '2016-11-14 19:00:00+0000' and time_Stamp <= '2016-11-14 20:00:00+0000' allow filtering
```

But it fails saying error given below:

> **ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}**

Column `time_stamp` is type of `timestamp`.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that (practically) your query timed out. You are asking Cassandra to scan all your dataset, and this is taking a lot of time.

The way you usually solve these problems is by getting rid of the `ALLOW FILTERING` in the query. That is, getting rid of the query, completely.

In other terms, you should rethink your data model.

Answer (score 1):

You must create your data model coherent with your queries in order to get rid of the `ALLOW FILTERING` option.

By this, your select queries will perform faster.

Please see:

[Basic Rules of Cassandra Data Modeling](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the table schema ?
In order to be able to use ">" and "<" operators on a column, you have to make sure it is a clustering column. (see [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause))

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. I have tried many things to overcome this. First of all, it increased the value of `tombstone_failure_threshold`.

And based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119894/10343888), I set `GC_GRACE_SECONDS` to `0`. Remember this is only a viable solution on a single node Cassandra. But these did not solve my problem.

I have browsed and read many resources and ask for a `timeout` as it says in the above answer.

I increased the value of the `read_request_timeout_in_ms` parameter in my `cassandra.yaml` file.

Then I was able to run all my queries without errors. I wanted to add this answer, albeit late, as I thought it might help someone.

Comment: don't increase `tombstone_failure_threshold` - you're hiding problem instead of fixingit

Comment: Yes it is, but I didn't have a table to rearrange its design. so hiding it was a good way, at least for my case.