# Read Failure in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a single node cassandra setup. I am getting the following error in cassandra cqlsh on running `select count(*) where` query on a table:

**Complete query:**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE
creation_time > '2018-09-16 00:00:00' and creation_time < '2018-09-16 23:59:59' 
ALLOW FILTERING;
```

**Response Message:**

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] 
message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" 
info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

**Table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS casb.o365_activity_log_by_date (
    current_date date,
    creation_time timestamp,
    insertion_time timestamp,
    id text,
    client_ip text,
    workload text,
    operation text,
    user_id text,
    object_id text,
    activity_detail text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((current_date), insertion_time, id)
    )
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC, id DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I have another python based application that is reading from that table and the job seems to be stuck.

**Logs:**

In `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`

```
WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-16 22:06:48,803 ReadCommand.java:533 - Read 58545 live rows and 100001 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE creation_time > 2018-09-16 00:00Z AND creation_time < 2018-09-16 23:59Z LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-16 22:06:48,804 StorageProxy.java:1906 - Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE creation_time > 2018-09-16 00:00Z AND creation_time < 2018-09-16 23:59Z LIMIT 100' (last scanned row partion key was ((2018-09-15), 2018-09-15 08:09Z, 72160ee4-5310-4941-af92-d27ced9c9ca8)); query aborted
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-09-16 22:07:02,937 SelectStatement.java:430 - Aggregation query used without partition key
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-09-16 22:07:45,946 SelectStatement.java:430 - Aggregation query used without partition key
WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-16 22:07:47,200 ReadCommand.java:533 - Read 58545 live rows and 100001 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE creation_time > 2018-09-16 00:00Z AND creation_time < 2018-09-16 23:59Z LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-16 22:07:47,200 StorageProxy.java:1906 - Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE creation_time > 2018-09-16 00:00Z AND creation_time < 2018-09-16 23:59Z LIMIT 100' (last scanned row partion key was ((2018-09-15), 2018-09-15 08:09Z, 72160ee4-5310-4941-af92-d27ced9c9ca8)); query aborted
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-09-16 22:17:52,810 SelectStatement.java:430 - Aggregation query used without partition key
WARN  [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-16 22:17:54,513 ReadCommand.java:533 - Read 58545 live rows and 100001 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE creation_time > 2018-09-17 00:00Z AND creation_time < 2018-09-17 23:59Z LIMIT 100 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2018-09-16 22:17:54,513 StorageProxy.java:1906 - Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date WHERE creation_time > 2018-09-17 00:00Z AND creation_time < 2018-09-17 23:59Z LIMIT 100' (last scanned row partion key was ((2018-09-15), 2018-09-15 08:09Z, 72160ee4-5310-4941-af92-d27ced9c9ca8)); query aborted
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2018-09-16 22:18:09,541 SelectStatement.java:430 - Aggregation query used without partition key
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2018-09-16 22:18:17,143 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-09-16 22:18:28,160 SelectStatement.java:430 - Aggregation query used without partition key
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-09-16 22:18:47,943 SelectStatement.java:430 - Aggregation query used without partition key
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:75] 2018-09-16 22:28:26,738 AutoSavingCache.java:394 - Saved KeyCache (48 items) in 250 ms
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2018-09-16 22:29:27,992 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index summaries
```

**More Details:**

I can run the following query on the same table without any errors:

`SELECT * FROM casb.o365_activity_log_by_date;`

Running above query I can see that there are some columns with mostly null values in them. Seeing this and from the logs I am guessing it has something to do with tombstones in cassandra.

What should I do here? I looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114455/reading-error-in-cassandra), so should I clean up tombstones? I am not sure.

Comment: Just as a note that query has to read the _entire_ data set from the whole cluster. If that doesnt fail from too many tombstones or something it would timeout

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses two maybe anti-patterns for Cassandra.

First, you are trying to count all keys in your entire database. This will result in reading all your entire data on disk in Cassandra as there are no indices as in an RDBMS which could answer your question quickly. Be alarmed that `SELECT * FROM foo;` or `SELECT count(*) FROM bar;` will always be slow in Cassandra.

Second, you ignored the warning from Cassandra to do those things - `ALLOW FILTERING` must be written explicitly. Keep in mind that this is meant for protecting you to do entire cluster reads. Your select statement is filtering on `creation_time` which is not part of your primary key.

So I would bet that you are hitting timeouts while your query runs. Have a look in your `system.log` from Cassandra, often found under `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` when installed from packages.

In general - if you want to use Cassandra I recommend going through some data modelling courses which are available from DataStax for example. It usually boils down to this: build your data model around the queries you will be using - denormalize if necessary, so that your queries ideally only hit one partition key.